# Can't access Meteor's mongodb from Python

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor

I am running Meteor on my Mac and want to access its mongo database from python on the same machine. When logging into the mongo shell, I get the following:

```
    $ meteor mongo
    MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
    connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

But when I try to access that mongo database from python, using pymongo, getting data in and out does work, but it's a different database, since the same collections and values are not available. For example, after running the lines below in python, the collection "test" is not available in Meteor, and vice versa:

```
    In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient
    In [2]: client = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor')
    In [3]: db = client.primer
    In [4]: db.test.insert_one({"data":3.141592})
    In [5]: db.test.find_one()
    Out[5]: {u'_id': ObjectId('56fd3ee4e9ff655a7ad5e13b'), u'data':3.141592}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code "db = client.primer" from the Mongodb.org site's examples. However, in the "db = client." you need to connect to "meteor" instead of "primer":

```
    db = client.meteor
```

Then it works.